# HTML: Elements and attributes. CSS: Selectors and ...?

Tags: css

What are the styling keywords such as top, margin, padding, background-color etc.. called in CSS?

Are they commonly referred to as `key:value pairs` or do they have other names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're called properties. And yes, it's key:value pairs for each selector. You can read more about them here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Syntax

Comment: Judging by his asking history I'm sure he'll get to it without a nag.

Comment: @torazaburo: i changed my ref with yours, if you don't mind, in my answer. I generally don't like w3schools, but, i just wanted to answer quickly. w3schools appear generally on top of the list when you google.